# ¿Que evento de ionic 2 llama constantemente una función al mantener oprimido un botón?

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2

Tengo un boton con el icono + para modificar la cantidad, lo que quiero es que para el usuario no tenga que dar `tap` o `click` constantemente, simplemente mantenga oprimido el botón y la cantidad aumente hasta que el usuario suelte el botón, como hago esto en ionic 2?

Ninguno de estos evento hace lo que necesito: tap, press, pan, swipe, rotate, y pincheventos.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacerte tu propia función "casera" que haga lo que pretendes? Te lo digo porque es muy sencillo lo que pretendes hacer sin necesidad usar de lo que mencionas, te recomiendo que siempre intentes programar las cosas que pretendas sin depender de otras librerías. Si quieres te puedo poner un ejemplo usando tan solo Java Script, pero eso depende de ti :)

Comment: no se como hacerlo, si me puedes indicar, por ahora estoy llamando la funcion por medio del evento (click) o (tap) pero es muy canson estar dando tanto clicks o taps para aumentar bastante la cantidad, quiero que esto se haga solo con mantener pulsado el boton. como hago esto?

Comment: ¿no te importa si es sin necesidad de usar las librerías que indicas? Yo si te ayudo es con un ejemplo usando JavaScript, por eso te pregunto.

Comment: dale, para hacerme una idea

Comment: dame un rato, que todavía no estoy en casa....

Comment: ya tienes la respuesta, espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo en el que se logra lo que pretendes hacer:

```js
var tStart = 'mousedown';
var tEnd = 'mouseup';

function touchSupport() {
    return ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? true : false; //Comprobamos si el dispositivo es táctil para decidir entre un evento u otro
}

if (touchSupport()) { //Si es táctil los eventos cambiarán
    tStart = 'touchstart';
    tEnd = 'touchend';
}

var btn = document.getElementById("add");
var timeout;
var interval;
var q = 0; //Cantidad {valor}

function write(val) { //Función que simplemente escribe el valor de cantidad
    document.getElementById("cantidad").innerHTML = val;
}

btn.addEventListener(tStart,function() { //Cuando se comienza a pulsar
    q++;
    timeout = setTimeout(function() { //Iniciamos el timeout
        interval = setInterval(function() { //Si el timeout llega a terminar iniciamos el intervalo
            q++;
            write(q);
        }, 50);
    }, 300);

    write(q);

});

btn.addEventListener(tEnd,function() { //Cuando se termine de pulsar
    clearTimeout(timeout); //Limpiamos el timeout
    clearInterval(interval); //Limpiamos el intervalo
});
```

```css
/* Nunca viene mal un poquito de CSS ;) */
#cantidad {
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#add {
  background: #0092ED;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="cantidad">0</div>
<button id="add">+</button>
<p>Mantener pulsado el botón + para incrementar rápidamente.</p>
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda

Comment: Casi lo logro, su ejemplo es bueno pero así no me permite pasarle la referencia del objeto al que necesito modificarle la cantidad, mejor dicho necesito un evento que llame miFuncion(parametro) siempre que el botón este oprimido, voy a marca como respuesta correcta, aun que lo que necesito aun no lo logro.

Comment: @DanielEnriqueRodriguezCaste se puede lograr lo que pretendes, pero necesito que me des más detalles, si quieres puedo crear una sala de chat y te ayudo.

Comment: Creo que ya lo logre, no era muy complicado, use parte del ejemplo que me paso, simplemente hice esto:     <button ion-button (mousedown)="agregar(producto)" (mouseup)="stop()" (mouseleave)="stop()" >-</button>
 y en JS:
 agregar(producto){
    producto.cantidad++;
        this.interval.push(setInterval(function () {
          producto.cantidad++;
        }, 150));

  } 
stop(){
      clearInterval(this.interval);//Limpiamos el intervalo
  }

Comment: aunque el único problema es que siempre que el mouse pasa por encima del botón y sale, se llama a la función stop(), se que hay un evento que llama cuando el usuario suelta el click fuera del boton.

Comment: Amigo, estoy necesitando ayuda con una pregunta, si me puede ayudar le agradezco, aquí le dejo el link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81937/como-haga-un-orderby-pipes-en-ionic-2