# ¿Como haga un orderBy pipes en Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2

Necesito organizar una lista de producto ordenado por un `Array` de `String` como propiedades del `Array` de objetos

**ejemplo: Caso 1**

```
<div *ngFor="let producto of productos| orderBy:'nombre,descripcion' : 'ASC' || 'DES'"></div>
```

**ejemplo: Caso 2**

```
<div *ngFor="let producto of productos| orderBy:['nombre','descripcion'] : 'ASC' || 'DES'"></div>
```

**ejemplo: Caso 3**

```
<div *ngFor="let producto of productos| orderBy: ordenPropiedades  : 'ASC' || 'DES'"></div>
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, estás buscando un ejemplo de pipe para implementar? Saludos

Comment: Estoy buscando construir mi propio orderBy pero no lo he logrado, seria muy sencillo de hacer un orderBy si simplemente fuera un arreglo de String, Ejemplo: ["Carlos", "Andres", "Juan", "David"], pero lo que necesito es que puede ordenar un arreglo de Objetos ordenándolo en el orden de la propiedades que le pase al filtro, como lo deje en los ejemplos de la pregunta

Comment: para mejor explicación, los objetos son productos, y estos tienen dos propiedades que quiero organizar en la lista, el primer orden, es que estén ordenados por categoría y luego de eso estén ordenados alfabéticamente

Comment: Algo asi como productos: Array<any> = [
    {nombre:'g_nombre', categoria:'aseo'},
    {nombre:'f_nombre', categoria:'aseo'},
    {nombre:'e_nombre', categoria:'alimentos'},
    {nombre:'d_nombre', categoria:'perecederos'},
    {nombre:'c_nombre', categoria:'aseo'},
    {nombre:'b_nombre', categoria:'alimentos'},
    {nombre:'a_nombre', categoria:'aseo'},
    ];  template: ` <div *ngFor='let nombre of nombres | orderBy:["categoria","nombre"]'>{{nombre.nombre}} - {{nombre.apellido}}</div> ` transform(array: any, by:string[]): Todo[] {} algo mas o menos

Comment: Algo así? http://plnkr.co/edit/aPVOFPAePidzPzNRNoAB?p=preview

Comment: Listo lo logre, me sirvió de idea lo que hiciste en lo ultimo, leí la documentación y se me ocurrió la solución. la dejo de comentario para que lo pruebes y si de alguna maneja la puedes optimizar ponlo en la respuesta, de lo contrario escribe mi solución como respuesta y te doy los puntos por ayudarme

Comment: var list=[ 
  {categoria:'categoria 1',name:'Edward',value:21},{categoria:'categoria 3',name:'Sharpe',value:2},{categoria:'categoria 3',name:'And',value:4534},{categoria:'categoria 1',name:'The',value:-12},{categoria:'categoria 4',name:'Magnetic',value:245},{categoria:'categoria 2',name:'Edward',value:257},{categoria:'categoria 1',name:'Sharpe',value:231},{categoria:'categoria 2',name:'And',value:764},{categoria:'categoria 1',name:'The',value:-237},{categoria:'categoria 2',name:'And',value:124},{categoria:'categoria 2',name:'Zeros',value:12346}]; var propiedades=["categoria","name", "value"];

Comment: for(var x=propiedades.length-1;x>=0 ;x--){var mapped=list.map(function(el, i){return{index:i,value:el};});mapped.sort(function(a,b){return +(a.value[propiedades[x]]>b.value[propiedades[x]]) || +(a.value[propiedades[x]]===b.value[propiedades[x]])-1;
   });var result=mapped.map(function(el){return list[el.index];});list=result;for(var xx=0;xx<list.length;xx++){console.log(list[xx]["categoria"], list[xx]["name"], list[xx]["value"]);}
}

Comment: Me alegra que haya servido de punta pié inicial :). Ahora lo miro y lo paso a la respuesta así que queda para cualquiera que pueda necesitarlo. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basado en tu comentario, dejo plasmada la respuesta para futuras referencias:

Archivo **miPipe.ts:**

```
@Pipe({ 
   name: 'ordenar' 
}) 

export class Ordenar implements PipeTransform { 
   transform(values: Array<any>, propiedades: string[], direccion: string[] ): Array<any> { 

   // en el atributo dirreccion se escribe "des" o "DES" para invertir el orden en sentido descendente y "asc" o "ASC" para un orden ascendente


   for( let x = propiedades.length-1; x >=0 ; x-- ){    
      let mapped = values.map(function( el, i ) {
         return { index: i, value: el };

       })
       mapped.sort(function(a, b) {
       return +( a.value[propiedades[x]] > b.value[propiedades[x]]) || +(a.value[propiedades[x]] === b.value[propiedades[x]] ) - 1;
       });

       values = mapped.map(function(el){
         return values[el.index];
       });
       if( direccion[x] === "des" || direccion[x] === "DES" ){
          values = values.reverse();
       }

   }
   return values;
   } 
}
```

Archivo **html**:

```
<ion-item *ngFor=" let producto of productos | ordenar: [ 'category', 'p_name', 'favorito' ] : [ 'asc', 'asc', 'des' ]; let i = index ">
 {{producto.p_name}}
 ...
</ion-item>
```

También dejo el ejemplo funcional en un plnkr, en el cual dejo incluida también la solución original por si alguien mas puede encontrar diferentes variaciones que les puedan ser de utilidad: http://plnkr.co/edit/aPVOFPAePidzPzNRNoAB?p=preview

Desde ya, muchas gracias y un saludo.